# How do you override "-moz-user-select: none;" on a child element?

Tags: css, cross-browser, textselection

The question *[CSS rule to disable text selection highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)* shows how to *prevent* text selection on an element. Once you have prevented selection, how can you then allow selection for a specific child element?

For example,

```
<div class="no-select">
    <p>some text that cannot be selected</p>
    <p class="select">some text that can be selected</p>
    <p>some text that cannot be selected</p>
</div>

table.no-select {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

td.select {
    -webkit-touch-callout: all !important;
    -webkit-user-select: all !important;
    -khtml-user-select: all !important;
    -moz-user-select: all !important;
    -ms-user-select: all !important;
    user-select: all !important;
}
```

The `.no-select` rule above works, but my attempt at a `.select` rule does not. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try `-moz-user-select: text` instead of `all`.

As a future reference, whenever concerned about the possible values for a CSS rule, check a site like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/CSS_Reference).

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) is the MDN link for `user-select`.